# Extract text from PDF/A in Java

Tags: java, api, pdf, apache-tika

Are there any Java Frameworks, that can extract text from PDF/A? There are many java PDF frameworks, but they don't specify, if they support that format.

Comment: Isn't PDF/A just a subset of PDF? Wouldn't that mean any reader that can read PDF can read PDF/A, however you might need specific support for creating a PDF/A (which isn't what you want anyways) because it needs to have all fonts, colour spaces, etc. embedded.

Comment: So did you try tika? It mentioned in tags.

Comment: if i understand pdf/a it is save more or less like an image? While other pdf can have their text in plain format.

Comment: I don't think that's actually the case. PDF/A archives must contain all fonts etc. that are used in the document, as @Jon Lin said, but otherwise they are just like PDF documents, and any PDF reader should be able to read them.

Comment: Okey thanks, then i gotten the wrong idea about pdf/a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonard Rosenthol did an excellent talk on PDF standards and formats at the itext summit. He explained all the different subsets. You can watch the video online at http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=3188&sl=0

There is a list of all the presentations at http://lowagie.com/summit2012presentations

Answer (score 1):

You should check http://itextpdf.com/ (specially [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=226) chapter). It is the best opensource framework to work with PDF files in Java I have ever used.